# Popcorn API: How to enable expansion on a custom translation?

Tags: rest, mapping

I'm using [Popcorn](https://github.com/SkywardApps/popcorn) to allow clients of my API to specify how deeply to unravel the properties of the requested object.

I'm having trouble mapping one of my data model entities to a projection. All the entities are entity framework data models so I'm using 'MapEntityFramework' where I can.

The data model looks like this:

```
public class DataModel {
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class Person {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Pet> Pets {get; set;}

    public List<Pet> GetLivingPets() {
       // Do some computation to get the pets that are alive
    }
}

public class Pet {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Alive { get; set; }
}

public PetProjection {
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}


public PersonProjection {
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public List<PetProjection> LivingPets {get; set;}
}
```

The request I'd like my clients to be able to make requests that specify the nesting of the dynamically generated list.
http://localhost:5000/api/1/Persons?include=[Id,LivingPets[Name]]

Which would return a list like this:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "LivingPets": [
            {
                "Name": "Capt Meowmix"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the mapping that I am attempting:

```
popcornConfig
.Map<Person, PersonProjection>(config: (personConfig) =>
{

     personConfig.Translate(fp => fp.LivingPets, f => f.GetLivingPets()?.ToList()); // Error: 'Dictionary<string, object>' does not contain a definition for 'GetLivingPets' and no extension method 'GetLivingPets' accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary<string, object>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   

})
.MapEntityFramework<Pet, PetProjection, DataModel>(dbContextOptionsBuilder);
```

What do I need to do to write a mapping that would make use of another mapping I've already defined? Is this something that can be done with the library? Am I missing something?

Comment: What are you actually getting if not what you expect?

Comment: The closest mapping I could get is `config.Translate(fp => fp.LatestPets, f => f.GetLivingPets()?.Select(...custom function to translate Pet to PetProjection...).ToList());` But that always returns the same object regardless of what the user specified in their `include`.

Comment: If I try to use `config.Translate(fp => fp.LivingPets, f => f.GetLivingPets()?.ToList());` I get `'Dictionary<string, object>' does not contain a definition for 'GetLivingPets' and no extension method 'GetLivingPets' accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary<string, object>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for the `Translate` on `LivingPets`. Popcorn automatically looks for same named properties between the mapped entity and its projection.  It'll look for matching properties, or failing that matching methods that require no parameters, so if you name your method `LivingPets` it'll automatically work.  However, what you're doing with the Translate should *also* work.

Regarding the translate function, as long as it returns an object Popcorn has a mapping for, the client should be able to expand it. You were seeing that error because the compiler was picking the wrong version of the Translate function. If you switch

```
personConfig.Translate(fp => fp.LivingPets, f => f.GetLivingPets()?.ToList());
```

to

```
personConfig.Translate(fp => fp.LivingPets, (f,c) => f.GetLivingPets()));
```

The compilation error should disappear. This is a bug and is being tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/SkywardApps/popcorn/issues/13).